# A question about when a triangle has a maximum area

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

First of all, I'm not asking for the answer to this question, but rather a hint, or a way to approach those kinds of problems.

**Problem:** Two sides of a triangle are a and b. What is the largest area the
triangle can have? What is the shape of the triangle with the largest area?

**Challenge:** There is another right triangle with sides a and b. Find
this triangle and its area.

The answer the book (Trigonometry by Gelfand) gave to the first part of the question, was a right triangle with an area of $ab/2$, which is okay, seems reasonable, but how would I discover such a thing? I'm stuck here.

Comment: Think about the fact that you want the height from a to be as large as it can be (since the size of a is already fixed)

Comment: Hmmm, I tried drawing the circumscribed circle of this triangle, the maximum height should be the radius of the circle, so the maximum area would be $1/2(a^2+b^2)$, Is this reasoning right? and if so, is there a special name for this triangle? or otherwise, why did he say "find the triangle and its area|.

Comment: Imagine that triangle and "play" with the angle between a and b (note that the whole triangle depends only on that angle). Think about how that height changes when you change this angle (you also can find an accurate formula for it using trigonometry). You have to see for what that height reaches its maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\theta$ be the angle between the two given sides. Even though $\theta$ is not specified, the area of the triangle will be $\frac12 ab\sin\theta$. This tells you that the area depends for given $a$, $b$ only on $\theta$. How does this area change as $\theta$ varies?

For the challenge problem, you'll get the same answer as before if the angle between $a$ and $b$ is $90$. If not, then either $a$ or $b$ is the hypotenuse. In that case, is there enough information to deduce the area? (For definiteness you can assume $a$ is the hypotenuse.)

Comment: The maximum area would be achieved when $\sin \theta = 1$, that is $\theta = 90$, and the area varies too as $\theta$ varies.

Comment: @HassanAshraf Correct, and $\theta=90$ corresponds to a right triangle.

Comment: But I still cannot see a way to tackle the challenge, I mean using this method, for example, I arrive at the same answer provided in the book, Can I get a hint for that maybe?

Comment: @HassanAshraf Please see my edit.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried drawing the circumscribed circle of this triangle, the maximum height should be the radius of the circle, so the maximum area would be $1/2(a^2+b^2)$, Is this reasoning right? and if so, is there a special name for this triangle? or otherwise, why did he say "find the triangle and its area"

Comment: @HassanAshraf For the challenge problem, the right triangle is completely determined once you assume the hypotenuse to be $a$ -- the area is fixed and there's nothing that can be maximized. I imagine 'find the triangle' means 'determine the side lengths of the right triangle' but I may be misunderstanding the question